# Wordpress: Custom shortcode to render image with meta data

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

My problem: **How to pull the media data out of the database in PHP**?

I'd like to write a shortcode that renders an image with the alt-text and caption taken automatically from the media database. Usage-example:

```
[img 126 300]  // [img media-id width]
```

Intended Output:

> [image: Demo image]
>
> *Caption from Database*

Comment: What have you tried? Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Media is just a post type of `attachment` and the caption data is in the postmeta table.

Comment: I did some research. I know there's a [`caption`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Caption_Shortcode) shortcode, a [`do_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) function and I've found the source of [`img_caption_shortcode`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.1.1/src/wp-includes/media.php#L0). However I can't find the way to access the media data :-/

Comment: That data is in the `wp_posts` table. The alt text is usually the `post_title` column and the caption is in the `post_excerpt` column. You can use `get_the_excerpt()` and `get_the_title()` functions.

Answer (score 1):

I was hoping for some wordpress-integrated function to get me the needed values in a few lines of code, but with @disinfor's hint I dug a bit into the wordpress database and came to the following results.

First an overview how an image and its metadata are saved in the Wordpress database:

- `wp_posts.post_title` is the **title** of the image
- `wp_posts.post_excerpt` is the **caption** of the image
- `wp_posts.guid` is the **url** of the image
- `wp_posts.post_content` is the **content** of the image's media page
- `wp_postmeta.meta_value WHERE meta_key='_wp_attachment_image_alt'` is the **alt-text** of the image

We don't need all of them since there indeed *are* some helper functions that make creation of our own image shortcode easier, namely [`wp_get_attachment_image`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/) and [`img_caption_shortcode`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/img_caption_shortcode/).

Code below (I've extended the shortcode to also give an arbitrary class to the image):

```
function img_shortcode($atts) {
    // Signature: [img <media_id> <width> <classes>], i.e. [img 126 300 "article-image"]
    // You may pass other keyword-attributes accepted from `img_caption_shortcode`
    // except 'class'. You can even override 'caption' manually

    global $wpdb;
    try {
        $conn = new \PDO("mysql:host=" . constant('DB_HOST') . ";dbname=" . constant('DB_NAME'), constant("DB_USER"), constant("DB_PASSWORD"));
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $conn->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        #echo "Connected successfully";

        $sql =  "SELECT post_excerpt FROM `". $wpdb->prefix . "posts` WHERE ID=". $atts[0] ."";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $caption = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['post_excerpt'];
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
        return NULL;
    }

    $a = shortcode_atts([
        'width' => $atts[1],
        'caption' => $atts['caption'] ? $atts['caption'] : $caption,
        'class' => $atts[2],
    ], $atts, 'img');

    $html = '<div class="image-container">';
    $html .= wp_get_attachment_image($atts[0], [$atts[1]], false, $a['class'] ? ["class" => $a['class']] : '');
    $html .= img_caption_shortcode($a);
    $html .= '</div>';
    return $html;
}

add_shortcode('img', 'img_shortcode');
```

It will output the following structure:

```
<div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://www.example.com/path-to-image.jpg" class="article-image" alt="alt-text from db" srcset="...all image-sizes from db" sizes="(max-width: 600px) 100vw, 600px" width="600" height="395">
    <div style="width: 610px" class="wp-caption alignnone article-image">
        <p class="wp-caption-text">The Captiontext</p>
    </div>
</div>
```